Confused about empty plastic bottle in the freezer situation
Note: When I say the bottle is "empty", take it to mean, "with just air inside", as we use in everyday life! :)
My question: Suppose we put an "empty" closed common plastic bottle in the freezer. Experience shows that the bottle will be deformed (pressed). Why is that?
I think It has to do with how air pressure varies with temperature, I believe. Is the air outside the freezer at a lower pressure than the air in the freezer? Does this makes sense?
2nd note: I know almost no physics outside basic knowledge of Newton's laws. Maybe this is explained in every good high-school physics textbook, but I did not find the answer by reading or my own reasoning. :( And it is something that intrigues me. I am very confused.
P.S. Sorry about my English, it's not my native language.

The air pressure is the same inside and outside your freezer, as your freezer isn’t sealed. However, the closed bottle is sealed. I agree with your reasoning that the pressure inside the bottle decreases as the enclosed air cools. This can be modeled with the ideal gas law, as air is near-ideal at familiar conditions. Using this law, you can estimate the pressure drop that drives the bottle to collapse. (Make sure to use the absolute temperature, in kelvins.)

I used to get milk in half-gallon glass bottles. Sometimes when I emptied one, I would leave it on the counter and eat my meal before rinsing it out. Most of the air in the empty bottle started at fridge temperature. Warming up for fifteen minutes was often enough to build a pressure difference that would pop the slip-on lid, which shot up about two feet in the air, with a satisfying thoom.

I think it would be more accurate to say that the volume of the gas decreases when it cools. The pressure does decrease, but it doesn't take much force (i.e. pressure difference) to deform the bottle, so it will change shape until the pressure inside the bottle is very similar to the pressure outside. Then you would use the ideal gas law $PV=nRT$ with fixed $P$ and $T$ to estimate the change in $V$.

This adds the additional assumption that the bottle material is near-perfectly compliant. I didn’t make this assumption, but one could. I think it’s clearest to think of the temperature change as causing a pressure differential (for all containers), which drives a volume change (mediated by the container stiffness) that recovers some of that pressure differential. I agree that if the container walls have minimal bending stiffness, then nearly all the pressure differential may be eliminated by their deformation.
